# During a Time Capsule 35 Pass Erase, do I have to keep my computer on / running?

Tags: wifi, time-machine, backup, airport, time-capsule

**Back Story:**

Okay, so I just upgrade my Time Capsule from a 2 TB (802.11n) to a 3 TB (802.11ac). Yay! However, after transferring over all my files, I needed to erase my old Time Capsule Partition.

I chose the 35 Pass Erase, because of the extremely sensitive data on this back up. (not really, but I just want to be safe).

**Question:**

So I started the erase! But I need to know if I turn off my computer, will the Time Capsule continue erasing on its own? Or if I loose my internet connection, will the Time Capsule keep erasing?

I really prefer not to have my computer on for that long, and I need to take my computer to work tomorrow...

**Other Notes:**

I am connected to my Time Capsule throughout Ethernet, and have WiFi disabled.

[image: Image of what is going on]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The The Time capsule doesn't need your Mac to run. Once it receives the wipe command, it will run to completion without needing anything but power from the all. (Ok - you could cancel the erase or it could error out, but in most cases the erase completes on its own accord.) You also don't need a Mac to start the wipe command. Airport Utility runs on Windows and iOS as well.